# Nice limit: $\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{\arcsin x}{x}\right)^{\frac1{x^2}}$

Tags: limits

Find

$$L=\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{\arcsin x}{x}\right)^{\frac1{x^2}}$$

Not much experienced with limits of this kind, I have tried to reduce this limit to a form without exponent:

$$\ln L=\lim_{x \to 0}\ln\left(\frac{\arcsin x}{x}\right)^{\frac1{x^2}}$$

$$\ln L=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln\arcsin x - \ln x}{x^2}$$

...and then I tried to apply L'Hospital to numerator and denominator. However, the solution becomes a complete mess and you can repeat derivation as many times as you want without ever reaching a conclusion.

I also tried to introduce substitution $x=\sin y$ which leads to:

$$L=\lim_{y \to 0}\left(\frac{y}{\sin y}\right)^{\frac1{\sin^2 y}}$$

This makes manipulation slightly easier but the same approach (L'Hospital after log) is still unable to generate a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that $\frac{\arcsin x}{x} \to 1$ as $x \to 0$, then

$$\ln L = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{\arcsin x}{x}-1\right)}{x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{\arcsin x}{x}-1}{x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\arcsin x-x}{x^3}.$$

Taking $x = \sin t$, the limit becomes

$$\ln L = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t - \sin t}{\sin^3 t} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t - \sin t}{t^3} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos t}{3t^2} = \frac{1}{6},$$

and hence $L = e^{1/6}$.

**Note:** Such method is useful to most of $1^{\infty}$-form limits.

Comment: This may be a stupid question , but  how did you get from$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{\arcsin x}{x}-1\right)}{x^2}$  to  $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{\arcsin x}{x}-1}{x^2}$ ?

Comment: @Britanica This is because $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{\arcsin x}{x}-1\right)}{\frac{\arcsin x}{x}-1} = 1$, where we have applied the standard limit $\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\ln(1 + t)}{t} = 1$.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

Use Taylor series (one piece at the time)
$$y=\left(\frac{\sin ^{-1}(x)}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}\implies \log(y)=\frac{1}{x^2}\log\left(\frac{\sin ^{-1}(x)}{x}\right)$$
$$\frac{\sin ^{-1}(x)}{x}=1+\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{3 x^4}{40}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
$$\log\left(\frac{\sin ^{-1}(x)}{x}\right)=\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{11 x^4}{180}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
$$\log(y)=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{11 x^2}{180}+O\left(x^4\right)$$
$$y=e^{\log(y)}=\sqrt[6]{e}+\frac{11}{180} \sqrt[6]{e} x^2+O\left(x^4\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Answer (score 2):

As you did take $x=\sin(y)$, $$\ln L=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\ln y-\ln(\sin(y))}{\sin^2(y)}\\=\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\frac 1 y-\cot(y)}{2\sin(y)\cos(y)}\\=\frac 1 2 \lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\frac {-1} {y^2}+ \csc^2(y)}{\cos(y)}\\=\frac 1 2 \lim_{y\to 0} \frac 1 {\sin^2(y)} - \frac {1} {y^2}\\=\frac 1 2 \lim_{y\to 0} \frac {1} {y^2} \left(\frac {y^2} {\sin^2(y)} - 1 \right)\\=\frac 1 2 \lim_{x\to 0} \frac {1} {\sin^2(x)} \left(\frac {\sin^2(x)} {x^2} - 1 \right)=\frac 1 2 \lim_{x\to 0} \frac {1} {\sin^2(x)}\left(1-\frac {2x^2}{3!}+\cdots-1\right)=\frac 1 6.$$

Note:- I used L'Hospital's rule without mentioning and also note that I used it even when the ratio is not in $\frac 0 0 , \frac {\pm\infty}{\pm\infty}$ so it may not satisfy you. I will post a more correct solution later, so you can downvote if you like. Sorry.